# Installing flask on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, flask

I have done this: [How to install Flask on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917254/how-to-install-flask-on-windows)
I currently have installed Python 3.4, which includes pip already.
When i run pip install flask in windows commandline as admin it returns

> C:\Python34>python.exe pip install flask
>
> python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Python IDLE returns

> pip install flask
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So, what have i done wrong? :/ I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Comment: `pip` is a command line tool, just like `python.exe` is.

Comment: `C:\Python34> pip install flask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` is a command line tool, not a Python module or command.

Just run it like:

```
C:\Python34> pip install flask
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could also run Flask on [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) or another free Python host - it has the added benefit of being able to access your code anywhere.