# Cant install any package from PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

Why I can not install any package from PyCharm on Windows? I have given full control in my user permissions to the recommended folders but I still get Permission denied I also try to install this as admin by command line.

In specific I am working with Python, and the library I want to install is Flask, but I can't install any package.

To avoid answers that have already been commented, I did the following commands as administrator:

```
pip install Flask
python -m pip install Flask
```

the error

```
Error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Comment: Try using a virtualenv?

Comment: yes error is the same even with a virtualenv, error seems like permissions admin but I cant find in which folder I can not install some package with pip! and Pip is correctly installed recently I have installed pytest with pip correctly but I can not install Flask!!.

Comment: If you're able to create a virtualenv, activate it, and still not be able to use pip from it, I really don't what to tell you. Maybe try installing Miniconda instead and see how far you can get

Comment: I did it, and still error! Error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: The problem is with permission but I dont know where, The problems occurs with many packages like Flask Django etc.

Comment: Can you open CMD as administrator and do it?

Comment: Yes I did it too, but can not install I am getting a little crazy. I will install pycharm and python into unit C and I will try again

Comment: If all else fails, use Docker or a VirtualBox

Comment: All failed this sucks. I will try with virtualBox or Docker Thanks for answer man

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Not sure where the actual problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
C:\Python34> pip install flask
```

If that is the directory for your python installation.

Referenced Articles:

[Installing flask on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731457/installing-flask-on-windows-7)

[How to install Flask on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917254/how-to-install-flask-on-windows)

Comment: I tried the command you posted but still : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:error: 'C:\\Users\\lopez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\ipython\\IPython\\lib\\security.py' And this happens for any package I want to install